# ¿Como retornar una respuesta Ajax a mi vista desde un controlador en Zend Framework 1?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend

Les comento, estoy intentando retornar un dato a mi vista busquedapersona, lo que hago es realizar una llamada ajax al servidor, específicamente al action mantenimientos/validarregistro, estos datos los muestro en un console.log(response), solo para probar, pero cuando me retorna la llamada en vez de pintarme el dato de respuesta me pinta el html. ¿Por que no se muestra la respuesta si estoy usando un echo en mi controlador php?. Necesito ayuda!
Este es mi código Javascript:

```
    $('#nrodoc').on('keyup', function(event){
        if($(this).attr('value').length == 8){
            $.ajax({
                url:jQuery.scriptPath+'index.php/mantenimientos/validarregistro',
                data: {dni: $('#nrodoc').attr('value')},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response){ 
                    $('#nrodoc').val('')
                    console.log(response);
                    openDialogWarning('El dni no es valido! ', 380, 150);                       
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    console.log('Disculpe, ocurrió un problema, Error: '+ error + ', Estado: ' +xhr.status)
                },
                complete: function(xhr, status){
                    console.log('Petición realizada')
                }
            });
        } 
    });
```

y mi código PHP es:

```
public function validarregistroAction() {
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->getHelper('ajaxContext')->initContext();
if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $url = $this->view->util()->getPath();
        if(($this->_getParam('dni'))!=null){
            $this->_redirect($url.'index.php/registro');
            $dni = $this->_getParam('dni');
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
            echo "Hello";
        }
}
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que te pinta el html? No me termina de quedar claro cuál es el problema que ocurre.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en la consola me pinta el codigo html... es decir <html><head>...</html> entiendes

Comment: ¿Es el html correcto?¿es lo que te tenía que devolver o es otra cosa (p.e. un  mensaje de error? Debes especificar mejor qué es lo que estás esperando recibir y qué es lo que recibes. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Quiero que solo me retorne el "Hello" escrito en mi código php. @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: ¿Y qué HTML te está respondiendo? Porque me estoy imaginando que es el HTML que se genera cuando ocurre un error en PHP y por eso no es lo que esperas.

Comment: No hay ningún error en el HTML es el de página correcta, solo que debería mostrarse solo el "Hello" y no toda la página

Comment: Llevo años sin tocar ZF1, apenas recuerdo sus comportamientos. 
¿Has probado a crear un _layout_ limpio, solo con `<?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>`, setear el _layout_ en el _action_ y pasarle a la vista el contenido que quieres mostrar?